# Angular directive dynamic template not working with bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a simplified version of a real problem but I want to understand what is happening and how to fix it. I have a directive that should load different templates deppending on a parameter that is being bind to it.

```js
var app = angular.module('my_app', [])
  .controller('controller', Controller)
  .directive('dirTwo', DirTwo);

function Controller() {
  var este = this;
  this.list = ["number", "text", "text"];
  this.change = function() {
    this.list = this.list.reverse();
  }
}

function DirTwo() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //template: ' Name: {{name}}{{type}}',
    template: my_template,
    scope: {
      type: "="
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "Pepito";
      console.log("scope type: " + $scope.type);
    }
  }
}
var my_template = function(elem, attrs, $scope) {
  console.log("template type: " + attrs.type);
  switch (attrs.type) {
    case 'number':
      return '<a href="#">{{type}}</a>';
      break;
    default:
      return ' ---- '
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app" ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="controller as App">
  <p>{{App.list}}
    <button ng-click="App.change()">Reverse</button>
  </p>
  <dir-two ng-repeat="item in App.list track by $index" type="item"></dir-two>
</div>
```

The log in the template function prints the word `item` instead of `number` or `text`. How can I fix it to load the template correctly?

Comment: tried `type="{{item}}"` ?

Comment: @GillesC, tried and the error is even bigger! In fact, you'll see that the binding works in the link function, but not in the template one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use `template` like that because the template resolution happens before the compile phase where your `type` would assume a value on scope. To change the template of a directive based on a scope value, you must watch that value and recompile the directive element when it gets changed. It will recompile the directive entirely with a new template but with the same scope. You could do this once (i.e., without the `$watch`) as well.

The following snippet implements this solution.

```js
var app = angular.module('my_app', [])
  .controller('controller', Controller)
  .directive('dirTwo', DirTwo);

function Controller() {
  var este = this;
  this.list = ["number", "text", "text"];
  this.change = function() {
    this.list = this.list.reverse();
  }
}

function DirTwo($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '',
    scope: {
      type: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      
      var tmplScope;
      
      scope.name = "Pepito";
      scope.$watch('type', function(type) {

        if (tmplScope) tmplScope.$destroy();

        tmplScope = scope.$new();

        element.html(getTemplate(type));
        $compile(element.contents())(tmplScope);
      });
    }
  }
}
var getTemplate = function(type) {

  switch (type) {
    case 'number':
      return '<a href="#">{{type}}</a>';
      break;
    default:
      return ' ---- '
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app" ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="controller as App">
  <p>{{App.list}}
    <button ng-click="App.change()">Reverse</button>
  </p>
  <dir-two ng-repeat="item in App.list track by $index" type="item"></dir-two>
</div>
```

> **UPDATE NOTE:** I've changed the actual compile system to create a new child scope every time it gets compiled and also destroy this child scope when it gets recompiled to prevent adding new `watchers` when recompiling it without discarding the previous ones. Thanks to @georgeawg who warnned about this issue in the comments.

Comment: Be aware that re-compiling templates will result in memory leaks. Each new  template will add watchers to the scope.

Comment: @georgeawg you're right sir! I didn't notice that. I first thought that it would be compiled once so it wouldn't be an issue at all. However, when recompiled, the scope was creating new watchers and keeping the old ones alive, that potentialy would create memory leaks with a certain numbers of recompile. Thank you for pointing this out for us, good observation. I've updated my answer as well.